# H2 database - embedded or server mode?

Tags: database, h2

I am using [Talend Open Studio for MDM](http://www.talend.com/products/mdm) which only supports a [H2 database](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforMDMInstallationandUpgradeGuide55EN/1.4+Compatible+Databases) for the back end storage.

Should I use H2 DB in embedded or server mode.

What is the difference between it?.

Answer (score 11):

H2 in embedded mode will be faster (3x to 4x) but no other process can access the DB.

If your DB needs to be shared between servers or APIs, then the server mode is needed. Caution there: you need to start the H2 server first either in your main java app or in a separate JVM process.

There's is a automatic mixed mode, allowing the first connection to benefit from embedded speed, while the next connections will be using the server mode. Caution again: the H2 server needs to be started first.

How to start H2 server: http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html?highlight=server&search=server#using_server

How to use automatic mixed mode: http://h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=AUTO_SERVER&search=AUTO_SERVER#auto_mixed_mode